# How to display old account from UTC file?

Tags: wallets, ether, accounts

I restored old UTC key file from another computer: UTC--2016-07-27T13-36-55.890168500Z--89f8704b0fdaabbb51c128c7fd9664ef218e1795 
and added it into keystore folder.
I also created fresh account with new installation: 
UTC--2017-05-31T18-10-39.282369700Z--f89d2b29ee41dd4ad71e720ecf4b883f14137d56
When I open Ethereum wallet and Mist I only see the new one inside.

How to display old account from UTC file? Is there additional step to restore/import the old account?

Thank you!

Comment: i thikns this can help you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10690/how-to-derive-the-private-key-from-utc-file